# ImportError: cannot import name 'tensorflow_backend' from 'keras.backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I decided to look at the implementation of the neural network in chats, and tried to run the code on my computer, but unfortunately nothing happened... Here is the console output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\Voice_ChatBot\bot.py", line 19, in <module>
    from text_to_text import TextToText
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\Voice_ChatBot\text_to_text.py", line 24, in <module>
    from seq2seq.models import AttentionSeq2Seq
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\seq2seq-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\seq2seq\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\seq2seq-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\seq2seq\cells.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\recurrentshop-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\recurrentshop\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\recurrentshop-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\recurrentshop\engine.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\recurrentshop-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\recurrentshop\backend\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\recurrentshop-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\recurrentshop\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'tensorflow_backend' from 'keras.backend' (C:\Users\akkenrl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py)
```

The repository from which I cloned the code: https://github.com/Desklop/Voice_ChatBot

Thanks in advance =)

In principle, I installed all the add-ons that were required, but for some reason he gave an error, decided to Google, but what they wrote there does not work at all or only makes it worse...